# How can I get timestamp, nonceStr and signature in wechat?

Tags: javascript, java, wechat

In wechat integration, I need `timestamp`, `nonceStr` and `signature` parameters. How can I get them using the app `access_token`?

Answer (score 0):

The **timestamp**, **nonceStr** and **signature** are parameters you need to create by yourself.
In Javascript, it would be like this :

```
   var date = new Date();
   var timestamp = Math.floor(d.getTime() / 1000);
   var nonce = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 15);
   var string = "param1=param1&param2=param2&noncestr=" + nonce + "&timestamp=" + timestamp; 
   var signature = SHA1(string);
```

This is just an exemple. In case of wechat integration, i advise to use this documentation if you dont speak chinese :

http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Getting_Started

http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Access_token

It's not updated but it can help you to figure out what do you need. and then you can compare with the official documentation to get the latest endpoint.

http://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki/7/aaa137b55fb2e0456bf8dd9148dd613f.html